# Webscraping monthly historical data from investing.com

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to Webscrape some index historical data from investing.com. However, being new to HTML, i have no idea how to modify the codes I found online in order to adapt them to my problem.

This is the code i found here:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Export_Table()

'Html Objects---------------------------------------'
 Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody
 Dim ieTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
 Dim Element As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection


'Workbooks, Worksheets, Ranges, LastRow, Incrementers ----------------'
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim Table As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set Table = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 '-------------------------------------------'
 Dim xmlHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  '
 '-------------------------------------------'


 i = 2

'Web Request --------------------------------------------------------------------------'
 With xmlHttpRequest
 .Open "POST", "https://www.investing.com/indices/germany-30-historical-data", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
.send "curr_id=951681&smlID=1695217&header=CLNX+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2017&end_date=03%2F01%2F2019&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data"


 If .Status = 200 Then

        Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
        Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body

        htmlBody.innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText

        Set ieTable = htmlDoc.getElementById("curr_table")

        For Each Element In ieTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Table.Cells(i, 1) = Element.Children(0).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 2) = Element.Children(1).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 3) = Element.Children(2).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 4) = Element.Children(3).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 5) = Element.Children(4).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 6) = Element.Children(5).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 7) = Element.Children(6).innerText

            i = i + 1
        DoEvents: Next Element
 End If
End With


Set xmlHttpRequest = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set htmlBody = Nothing
Set ieTable = Nothing
Set Element = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CreateHTMLDoc() As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function
```

My issue is with the line :

```
.send "curr_id=951681&smlID=1695217&header=CLNX+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2017&end_date=03%2F01%2F2019&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data"
```

I have no idea how to get the curr_id and smlID info, as well as the header.... I've tried a few other methods not involving XML requests, but the need to select "Monthly" from the drop down menu and the dates made it harder than I thought.

Any ideas about how and where to get the curr_id and smlID informations? I believe with these 2 I could probably manage, although I have 0 experience in HTML so not really sure.